# Importing data from pipedrive API in Google sheets. How to copy the data into the sheet in the correct columns and rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, pipedrive-api

I am trying to import all [Pipedrive](https://www.pipedrive.com) deals and writing the information I need in Google sheets.

What I am already able to do: Access the feed and parse the data to a variable.
And print this variable into 1 cell. Of course this isn't workable yet.

The code is somewhat scavenged (building while I'm learning)

```js
// Standard functions to call the spreadsheet sheet and activesheet
function alldeals() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

   //the way the url is build next step is to itterate between the end because api only allows a fixed number of calls (100) this way i can slowly fill the sheet.
  var url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?start=";
  var url2 = "&limit="
  var start = 0;
  var end = start+50;
  var token  = "&api_token=hiddenforobviousreasons"


  //call the api and fill dataAll with the jsonparse. 
//then the information is set into the 
//dataSet so that i can refill datall with new data.

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+start+url2+end+token); 
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
  var dataSet = dataAll;


  //create array where the data should be put
  var rows = [], data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.id, data.value,data.pipeline_id]); //your JSON entities here
  }

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 3); // 3 Denotes total number of entites
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

}
```

The error I am getting on the `sheet.getRange`.

What I want to achieve is put the data in the columns id, value, pipeline_id

Any pointers to what direction I need to go to solve this problem would be awesome! A fix would be nice to but some pointers would be more useful for my understanding.

The error i am getting is the following:

De coördinaten of afmetingen van het bereik zijn ongeldig. (regel 29, bestand 'dealpull5.0')

Loosely translated:

The coordinates of the size of the reach are invalid (line29,file "dealpull5.0")

Comment: Could you edit your code comments to English, please? What error are you getting from `sheet.getRange()`?

Comment: I translated the comments into english, and added the error at the end. Thanks for checking my message out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've retrieved data from a web API, and transformed it into a 2-dimensional array (an array of rows, where each row is an array of cells). To confirm this, you can add a Logger call after the loop that grooms the data:

```js
  var rows = [], data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.id, data.value,data.pipeline_id]); //your JSON entities here
  }

  Logger.log( JSON.stringify(rows,null,2) );   // Log transformed data
```

If you run that, you should see something like this in your logs:

```js
[--timestamp--] [ 
   [ id1, value1, pipeline_id1 ],
   [ id2, value2, pipeline_id2 ],
   ...
]
```

Next, you want to write it into a spreadsheet, which looks like this:

```
     A       B         C
1 | ID   | Value | Pipeline_Id |
  +------+-------+-------------+
2 |      |       |             |
3 |      |       |             |
```

The error message is complaining that the size of the range and size of your data do not match.

Things to note:

- Since there are column headers, the first cell that will contain data from the API call will be `A2`, which is also expressed as `R2C1`.
- When using `Range.setValues()`, all rows of the provided data must be the same length as the width of the range. If necessary, you may need to pad or trim the data before calling `Range.setValues()`.
- It is convenient to match the range size to the size of the data; that way, you can easily adapt to changes in the data retrieved from the API.

  ```js
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
  ```

Comment: Hey Mogsdad, Thanks for your help! found out that the array at rows isn't filling up but now i know where the error is comming from!

Comment: Got it working :) was getting the wrong array. now to build the  second loop! thanks for your help mogsdad

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this post!
I reworked your code for some of my needs to return the array of matching deals directly.

I also changed the api request to only pull specific deal fields, pull back 500 deals, and use a PipeDriver filter we've setup.

```
// Standard functions to call the spreadsheet sheet and activesheet
function GetPipedriveDeals() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

   //the way the url is build next step is to iterate between the end because api only allows a fixed number of calls (100) this way i can slowly fill the sheet.
  var url    = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals:(org_name,title,owner_name,status,pipeline_id)?start=";
  var limit  = "&limit=500";
  var filter = "&filter_id=1";
  var pipeline = 7; // put a pipeline id specific to your PipeDrive setup 
  var start  = 0;
//  var end  = start+50;
  var token  = "&api_token=your-api-token-goes-here"


  //call the api and fill dataAll with the jsonparse. 
  //then the information is set into the 
  //dataSet so that i can refill datall with new data.

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+start+limit+filter+token); 
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
  var dataSet = dataAll;

  //create array where the data should be put
  var rows = [], data;

  for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.data.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet.data[i];

    if(data.pipeline_id === pipeline){ 
      rows.push([data.org_name, data.title, data.owner_name, data.status, data.pipeline_id]);//your JSON entities here
    } 
  }
  Logger.log( JSON.stringify(rows,null,2) );   // Log transformed data

  return rows;
}
```