# Importing data from Pipedrive API in Google Sheets - custom fields?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api, pipedrive-api

I have been reading bits and bobs around the place to try and get into the API stuff for a while now (admittedly almost everything is beyond me), found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239701/importing-data-from-pipedrive-api-in-google-sheets-how-to-copy-the-data-into-th#) post which I was able to link our **[Pipedrive](https://www.pipedrive.com/)** into Google Sheets with however it seems to stumble when I try to work with a custom field API key that starts with numbers?

i.e. seems to stumble on the push of data.132... (7th row from bottom)

Any clues/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```js
// Standard functions to call the spreadsheet sheet and activesheet
function GetPipedriveDeals() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

   //the way the url is build next step is to iterate between the end because api only allows a fixed number of calls (100) this way i can slowly fill the sheet.
  var url    = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals:(org_name,title,owner_name,status,pipeline_id,value,a4f55810dfde1c6bead0709c5e0362a693e1a737,132c9a542e33bb3a2af984585eab85a0ee95b708)?start=";
  var limit  = "&limit=500";
  var filter = "&filter_id=64";
  var pipeline = 1; // put a pipeline id specific to your PipeDrive setup 
  var start  = 0;
//  var end  = start+50;
  var token  = "&api_token=YOUR_API_TOKEN"


  //call the api and fill dataAll with the jsonparse. 
  //then the information is set into the 
  //dataSet so that i can refill datall with new data.

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+start+limit+filter+token); 
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
  var dataSet = dataAll;

  //create array where the data should be put
  var rows = [], data;

  for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.data.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet.data[i];

    if(data.pipeline_id === pipeline){ 
      rows.push([data.title, data.org_name, data.owner_name, data.status, data.pipeline_id, data.a4f55810dfde1c6bead0709c5e0362a693e1a737, data.value, data.132c9a542e33bb3a2af984585eab85a0ee95b708]);//your JSON entities here
    } 
  }
  Logger.log( JSON.stringify(rows,null,2) );   // Log transformed data

  return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipedrive engineer here. I think you have javascript object property referencing issue - it cannot start with numbers. Try:

`rows.push([data.title, data.org_name, data.owner_name, data.status, data.pipeline_id, data['a4f55810dfde1c6bead0709c5e0362a693e1a737'], data.value, data['132c9a542e33bb3a2af984585eab85a0ee95b708']]);//your JSON entities here`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much! I though it must be something very similar just couldn't quite get it.